# BIM 360 Links issue

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

We are working on an Add-In that makes web requests on Startup. Everything works fine. The only issue is BIM360, when our Add-In is installed in Revit 2021.1.3 and opens an RVT coming from a 2019 version, Revit updates the model and the cloud links get lost and when you click on "Add Link" BIM 360 does not load the folders within BIM 360.
When you uninstall our plugin, the update and load of links works well. No errors are thrown in any case.
Have any of you experienced this issue before?

Comment: Can you provide more information on the problem? Better still, a minimal reproducible case with exact steps to reproduce? -- https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#1b -- I would like to pass on your question to the development team, but it is too vague in its current form for them to be able to respond anything useful.

Comment: Good afternoon @JeremyTammik,
We wanted to have all the information before replying.
Using Revit 2021.1.3, we open a central cloud model (created with rvt 2021.1.3) hosted in BIM 360. This revit model has several Revit links hosted in BIM360 (created with rvt 2021.1.3). If you have the pro version of Nonica (v2.4) installed, when you open the central file the revit links in that file appear as Not Loaded and when you try to reload using "Reload From", in the dialog it does not appear the folder breakdown neither the revit link files. We will send link to video to jeremy.tammik@autodesk.com

Comment: We think it could be related to the following:

var versionNumber = uiControlledApplication.ControlledApplication.VersionNumber;
var fieldName = versionNumber == "2017" ? "m_uiapplication" : "m_application";
var fi = uiControlledApplication.GetType().GetField(
    fieldName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var uiApplication = (UIApplication)fi.GetValue(uiControlledApplication);

We use this to get the logged in user onStartup. Would you know a way around to get that information?

Comment: I passed on this question to my BIM360 API expert colleagues for you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it! It looks that there was some kind of compatibility issue with Nuget Package Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.1. I updated that package to v12.0.3 and the issue went away.
Thank you very much and it would be great if you could pass the issue to Autodesk development team.

Comment: Congratulations on solving it. Sure, will do.